# JPA two transaction updating the same rows

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, concurrency, transactions

I'm using JPA repository in my SpringBoot app I have a background task that periodically set certain element in my database to 'ready'
I also have an endpoint that a user can call and that can modify the one of the row of that same table.

Is there a way to avoid one and another to cancel each other writes? Take this scenario

```
Table: 
Key
id     name      is_ready
```

0) Initial data there a key (1     no_name     false)

1) the background task kicks in and is about to modify the table Key by setting

```
is_ready to true
Key key = repo.findKeyByIsReady(false)
key.setIsReady(true)
repo.save(key) <--- does NOT yet execute this
```

2) a user call the api endpoint to change a key name to "new_name" and complete

3) now the background service execute the repo.save(key) and the final data is

```
1    no_name   true
```

instead of

```
1    new_name   true
```

basically the background task has overwritten the key name set by the user

is there a way to avoid this kind of scenario? How are transaction going to be helpful here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is usually solved via additional locks:

## Optimistic Lock

You detect in 2nd transaction that the row was changed by someone else. Then you either tell that to user and ask to fix manually or try to merge changes automatically.

To implement it you'd have to add additional column to the table - version. Then when updating the row the query would look something like this:

```
UPDATE ..., version=old_version+1 WHERE id=old_id and version=old_version
```

If `WHERE` close doesn't find the row (because someone else incremented the version), the number of changed rows would be 0 (JDBC gets this info from DB) and JPA would throw an error in this case.

The additional field would have to be mapped as `@Version` in JPA.

## Pessimistic Lock

Every time you update the entity you use construction:

```
select ... for update
```

When 2nd transaction issues such statement, DB locks that request until 1st transaction finishes. If this doesn't happen within a specific period of time, you get an exception from JPA. See `EntityManager#lock()` method for more information.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to solve this problem -

1. Update only the is_ready field

   - In your background task, instead of updating all fields of the record, update only the is_ready field. That way, you won't override changes to other fields
2. Lock rows by using transactions with a stricter database isolation level -

   - MySQL offers [all standard database isolation levels](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html#isolevel_serializable)
   - You can use the 'SERIALIZABLE' isolation level
   - Under this level, once you start a transaction and read a row, no other transaction can update that same row until the first transaction commits (or rollbacks)
   - So in your case, even if both processes manage to read the row in the same old state, only one of them would be able to update it successfully. The other process would fail to update the record (I've NOT tested this myself but that is how it is supposed to work under this isolation level)
   - You can use Spring's @Transactional annotation to mark the isolation level like this - `@Transactional(isolation=Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)`
   - Note that you have to be careful while using such a strict isolation level. Incorrect usage involving reads from multiple tables may cause deadlocks